# LuaTeX and polyglossia -> Warnings

Tags: miktex, luatex, polyglossia, luaotfload

I am using an up-to-date version of MikTeX. As soon as I compile a document with LuaLaTeX and including the package polyglossia I get two warnings:

> 1. Module luaotfload-main warning: LuaTeX v0.76 is old, v0.79 or later is recommended.
> 2. LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command" - Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 144. (-> *fontspec-patches.sty*)

I would like to get rid of those.

Comment: Well, you can always [download](http://www.luatex.org/download.html) the latest versions yourself.

Comment: *I would like to get rid of those.* -- You can get rid of the first one by updating you Luatex engine.

Comment: @phg: miktex has no update for luatex yet. Someone would have to make a feature request. Is the update needed for something in luaotfload?

Comment: None that I know of but I can only support the Luatex version in TeX Live as well as the latest SVN trunk. But it’s not that big of a deal: after all, we’re talking about a harmless warning, not an error.

Answer (score 3):

It's more a hack than a fix, but if you only want to get rid of the LuaTeX version warning and maybe wait for an official update from MikTex, you can edit the file `MiKTeX\tex\luatex\luaotfload\luaotfload-main.lua` and comment the warning out:

`--[[` starts a comment block, `--]]` closes it.

```
if tex.luatexversion < min_luatex_version then
--[[
    warning ("LuaTeX v%.2f is old, v%.2f or later is recommended.",
             tex.luatexversion  / 100,
             min_luatex_version / 100)
--]]
    --- we install a fallback for older versions as a safety
    if not node.end_of_math then
```

Answer (score -1):

Just install Texlive 2014 instead of miktex.